# List of similar questions appears blank when voting to close as duplicate

Tags: bug, status-declined

I haven't been able to figure out why, but something is causing the list of similar questions to appear blank, when voting to close a question as a duplicate. Example [Why is (...) useful in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397644/why-is-useful-in-r)

[image]

The HTML and CSS look just fine in the Chrome dev tools:

[image]

So I'm not sure what's going on here.

I'm running Chrome Version 41.0.2272.43 beta (64-bit) on OS X 10.9.5.

The issue does not occur in Safari 7.1.3, Chrome Canary Version 42.0.2298.0 canary (64-bit), nor Firefox 35.0.1.

[After exporting the complete page from Chrome,](https://github.com/mjball/Stack-Overflow-Q-A/tree/master/meta/q285628) I can reproduce the issue by opening the exported version in Chrome again; opening *the exact same export* in the other browsers shows a correctly-rendered list.

Comment: It's most likely a bug in that beta build, which Stack Exchange doesn't support.